# My Java program on Eclipse stopped printing out to the console but it was working correctly before

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a Pig Latin translator for a class. I had my program working before; it was printing out in the bottom for loop from the translatedWords array list. But the latest version does not print in the bottom for loop. I suspect it's a curly bracket but I can't seem to find it.

```
package stringTest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userString = "THIS IS A STRING";

        // We might need to trim the string first it throws an error if           theres
    // white space around word
    // Making string lowercase, first
    userString = userString.toLowerCase();

    // Splitting up string into individual words
    String[] stringArray = userString.split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> translatedWords = new ArrayList<String>();

    // going through each string with foreach loop
    for (String ss : stringArray) {
        System.out.println("prints here in intial for loop");
        // pulling out the words that start with a vowel
        // since they just get "way" at the end
        if (ss.charAt(0) == 'a' || ss.charAt(0) == 'e'
                || ss.charAt(0) == 'i' || ss.charAt(0) == 'o'
                || ss.charAt(0) == 'u') {
            ss = ss.concat("way");
            translatedWords.add(ss);

        }

        // If the words don't start with a vowel
        // trying to figure out how to cut them at first vowel and
        // concatenate to end
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < ss.length();) {
                if (ss.charAt(i) == 'a' || ss.charAt(i) == 'e'
                        || ss.charAt(i) == 'i' || ss.charAt(i) == 'o'
                        || ss.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                    ss = ss.substring(i, ss.length());
                    String sss = ss.substring(0, i + 1);
                    String ss44 = ss.substring(i + 1);
                    String ss33 = ss44 + sss;
                    ss33 = ss33 + "ay";
                    translatedWords.add(ss33);
                    System.out.println(ss33);
                    System.out.println("Why won't this print");
                    break; 

                }
            }

        }

        for (String fs : translatedWords) {
            System.out.print(fs.toString() + " ");
        }

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a curly bracket but the for loop is running infinitely

The `i` is never incremented in for statement or inside the for

So the if condition will keep on running for the first character of the string ,if it is not a vowel which will be false for the string 'this', so it will never get inside the if statement

```
  //for (int i = 0; i < ss.length();) {//no i++ implemented
  for (int i = 0; i < ss.length();i++) {
            if (ss.charAt(i) == 'a' || ss.charAt(i) == 'e'
                    || ss.charAt(i) == 'i' || ss.charAt(i) == 'o'
                    || ss.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                ss = ss.substring(i, ss.length());
                String sss = ss.substring(0, i + 1);
                String ss44 = ss.substring(i + 1);
                String ss33 = ss44 + sss;
                ss33 = ss33 + "ay";
                translatedWords.add(ss33);
                System.out.println(ss33);
                System.out.println("Why won't this print");
                break; 

            }
        }
```

Comment: this does not explain why it is not printing

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah added detail why it wont and it's a simple if logic